# How to extract public key from p7b certs with CryptoAPI

Tags: cryptography, cryptoapi

I have a p7b certificate store. I open it with

```
$HCERTSTORE cert_store_handle = CertOpenStore(
    CERT_STORE_PROV_PKCS7,
    PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
    NULL,
    CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG | CERT_STORE_READONLY_FLAG,
    &opm_data_blob
    );
```

I do cert chain verification, and it ok, till I have to extract public key from the leaf certificate.
I call

```
CryptDecodeObject(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB, (BYTE*) pubkey + 46, pubkey_len - 46, CRYPT_DECODE_NO_SIGNATURE_BYTE_REVERSAL_FLAG, NULL, &pubkey_decoded_size);
```

but it returns ASN1 bad tag error.

So I try the following code:

```
{
    BOOL crypt_res = FALSE;

    HCRYPTPROV crypt_prov_hndl = NULL;
    crypt_res = CryptAcquireContext(&crypt_prov_hndl, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0/*CRYPT_NEWKEYSET*/);

    if (!crypt_res) {
        HRESULT decode_hr = __HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        return decode_hr;
    }

    HCRYPTKEY crypt_key_hndl = NULL;
    crypt_res = CryptImportPublicKeyInfoEx(crypt_prov_hndl, X509_ASN_ENCODING, signer_public_key, CALG_RSA_SIGN, 0, NULL, &crypt_key_hndl);

    if (!crypt_res) {
        HRESULT decode_hr = __HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        return decode_hr;
    }

    crypt_res = CryptReleaseContext(crypt_prov_hndl, 0);
}
```

and it works fine, but still I don't know how to extract public key.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any specific format you want your public key to be in when you "extract" it?

Answer (score 0):

After opening the certificate store,

Enumerate all the certificates in the certificate store, `CertEnumCertificatesInStore`,

Once you get the context of the certificate of interest, you can access your public key in the `CERT_INFO` structure.